# grep regex match email address

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file `test.txt` which contains the following content:

```
BC@ABSC.CA
ABCabc+-._@mcmaster.io.ca
ABCabc+-._@school.image
ABCabc+-._@school3-computer.image
ABCabc+-._@school3-IT.image.tor.chrome.ca
ABCabc+-._@school3-IT.image.tor.chrome.canadannn
ABC123abc+-._@school3-IT.imageal.tor.chrome.canadannn
ABCabc+-._@school3-*IT.image.tor.chrome.ca
ABCabc+-._@school3-IT.image.tor.chrome.caskdlfj
ABCab*c+-._@school3-IT.image.tor.chrome.caABCabc
```

I then use

```
grep -E '^[A-Za-z0-9+._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}' test.txt
```

trying to match valid email. **The key here is that the last subdomain has to be a sequence of 2 to 6 char.**

So I am hopping to the get the following output:

```
BC@ABSC.CA
ABCabc+-._@mcmaster.io.ca
ABCabc+-._@school.image
ABCabc+-._@school3-computer.image
ABCabc+-._@school3-IT.image.tor.chrome.ca
```

But i ***also*** get the following even tho the length of the last domain succeed
6 chars.

```
ABCabc+-._@school3-IT.image.tor.chrome.canadannn
ABC123abc+-._@school3-IT.imageal.tor.chrome.canadannn
ABCabc+-._@school3-IT.image.tor.chrome.caskdlfj
```

How do i solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote

Comment: It's because you have multiple subdomains (not just 1). Put a `$` at the end.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Hi, i've tried putting $ at the need but it returned nothing then

Comment: I just tried running `grep -E '^[A-Za-z0-9+._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$' test.txt` and got exactly the result you were looking for.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I run the exactly same command on ubuntu but got nothing back. no sure why.

Comment: Do you need to escape the `$` or something weird like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `grep` matches anything in a line. If you want the exact whole line, add the `$` terminator at the end. Let's look at an example:

```
ABCabc+-._@school3-IT.image.tor.chrome.canadannn
```

1. `ABCabc+-._` matches `^[A-Za-z0-9+._-]+`
2. `@` matches `@`
3. `school3-IT.image.tor.chrome.` matches `([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+`. As far as I know, all quantifiers are greedy in `grep`.
4. `canada` matches `[a-zA-Z]{2,6}`
5. `nnn` gets ignored

Without the `$`, there just has to be some *part* of the line that matches, not necessarily the whole thing.

Comment: Why does `.chrome` match `[a-zA-Z]{2,6}`. My regex only allows lowercase and uppercase letter.

Comment: @Jackddddd. Sorry, put the dot in the wrong place and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add an endline anchor to your regex: `$`:

```
grep -E '^[A-Za-z0-9+._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$' test.txt
```

More about it: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Answer (score -1):

You can fix your query by adding a `$` at the end of your string.

```
grep -E '^[A-Za-z0-9+._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$' test.txt
```

Here is a live demo: https://regex101.com/r/NtZJQ0/1

Comment: But `([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+` this part ensures that each subdomain has to end with a `.`, isn't it?

Comment: The problem is already solved if you just add an anchor `$` at the end of the regular expression. See my updated answer. You can also try it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/NtZJQ0/1).